# How to clone and restore FreeRadius setup in another server?

Tags: radius, freeradius

I have an up and running `Freeradius` instance in Ubuntu server with several configuration changes. Is there a standard way of cloning this radius server to another server with same configurations. 
My current idea is to install `Freeradius` to the second server and replacing the raddb/ folder contents with the first installation. Is it going to work.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything is self-contained within raddb.  You could also theoretically create your own debian package which provides 'freeradius-config' and use that to install your custom configuration.